# php 7 mongodb collection insert

Tags: php, mongodb

We've installed php mongo ext and then have the composer set up as well.

https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter

In my php code I've this:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://host1,host2",  array ('replicaSet' => 'host-set-01'));
$document = array(....);
$db->mycollection->insert($document);
```

And it returned this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Collection::insert()

But inside the adapter's folder I do see `insert()` inside that collection class Mongo/MongoCollection.php

Anyone got it working with the mongodb/adapter?

Comment: Can you please post the correct fix for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `insertOne()` or `insertMany()` instead!

Answer (score 1):

This might be help you:

```
    $mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");    
    $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

    $doc = array(
        'id'      => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID,     #Generate MongoID
        'name'    => 'harry',
        'age'     => 14,
        'roll_no' => 1  
    );

    $bulk->insert($doc);
    $mongo->executeBulkWrite('schooldb.student', $bulk);    # 'schooldb' is database and 'student' is collection.
```

Here By using BulkWriter you can do insert,update and delete operation with one or more than one document.

Answer (score 0):

The client in the library that you link to (https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter) is `\MongoClient`, not `MongoDB\Client`.

The `Mongo/MongoCollection.php` class is `\MongoCollection`, not `MongoDB\Collection` as your error suggests.

I think you're trying to use a PHP extension version of Mongo and not the library that you have linked to.